# Android Gradle: Copying META-INF to META_INF "build/classes/{buildType}/" or retaining META-INF in .apk

Tags: java, android, gradle, apk

Using Android Gradle plugin version 0.7.3 with Gradle 1.9 all the contents of build/classes/{buildType}/META-INF/ are excluded from the packaged .apk.

See: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59658
com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder has:
line 959: !folderName.equalsIgnoreCase("META-INF") &&

So to rectify this, I'd like to move all the files in:
build/classes/{buildType}/META-INF/ -> build/classes/{buildType}/META_INF/
before the APK is packaged.

To generate my META-INF/services/* files, I'm currently using http://metainf-services.kohsuke.org/ with ... - and it works.

```java
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'org.kohsuke.metainf-services:metainf-services:1.5'
    ...
}
```

Now I need to auto-copy them after the compile process has finished, and add them to the classpath, but it doesn't work.

I'm using:

```java
android.applicationVariants.all{ variant ->
    variant.javaCompile.doLast{
        println "${buildDir}/classes/${variant.name}/META-INF"
        copy {
            from ("${buildDir}/classes/${variant.name}/META-INF/") {
                include '**/*'
            }
            into "${buildDir}/classes/${variant.name}/META_INF/"
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing is printed out, and nothing is copied.

I also tested with --info and --debug and "META" is nowhere to be found in the output.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any better method of solving this problem?

**Edit:**

Using the following, the folder is copied - but not present in .APK:
Is there any way to include it in the APK?

```
android.applicationVariants.all{ v ->
    task "${v.name}CopyFiles" (type: Copy)
    "${buildType.name}CopyFiles" {
        def base = "${buildDir}/classes/${buildType.name}"
        from "${base}/META-INF/"
        into "${base}/META_INF/"
    }

    v.processJavaResources.dependsOn "${buildType.name}CopyFiles"
}
```